# Filter Cookie names with regular expression

Tags: jquery, cookies, filter

I am using the below code to filter all the cookies stored using a regular expression.

```
 $.cookies.filter( '/^'+path+'/' ).each(function(a)
 {
        alert($.cookies.get(a));
 });
```

It seems the way I wrote regular expression is wrong. Please help on this.
I am using [this](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation#With_jQuery) library to deal with Cookies.

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Initially I am storing some cookies with my code and then When user wants I am retrieving the previously stored data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myRegex = new RegExp('/^'+path+'/');
$.cookies.filter( myRegex ).each(function(a){
   alert($.cookies.get(a));
});
```

The syntax for regular expressions is either delimited by `/` (without any quotes) or as a string passed to `RegExp` class. I don't know how to include variables if you define as `/` delimited regex, but without variables it would look like this...

```
$.cookies.filter( /^regex_pattern/ ).each( ... )
```